# Вывод в консоли деление уголком двух целых чисел.

Tags: c++

Задание такое: вводятся два числа, если они целые, то вывести на экран деление уголком этих двух чисел, если нет, то вывести на экран сообщение об ошибке.

не могу понять как реализуется программа. вот моя попытка:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int m,n,ch,t,k=0,s,e,g=0,c,q,a,f=0,d,u,l,i,h,ikr;
cout«"Введите числа m и n"«endl«endl;
cin»m; cin»n; cout«endl«endl;

if ( float(m)-m==0 || float(n)-n==0)
{ cout«m; cout«"|"«n«endl;
t=m; s=m;h=s;
e=m;
ikr=n+1;
l=m;
ch=m/n;
while (h>0) { h=h/10; g=g+1; }
i=g;
cout«setw(g+1)«"|"«ch«endl;
while (ikr>n) {

}

cin.get();
}

cin.get();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте код

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что: вопрос покинут автором.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное лучше ввести два числа, как строки.

Проверить что они состоят только из символов от '0' до '9' (десятичных цифр). Заполнить этими цифрами два массива (например char d1[100] и char d2[100]), преобразуя каждый символ в число, соответствующее десятичной цифре (например d1[i] = c1[i] - '0' это если в c1[] символы первого числа, а d1[] соответствующий массив цифр). Потом видимо надо выровнить, заполняя нулями.

Затем запрограммировать действия (смоделировать) деления "уголком" (мне это больше известно под названием "в столбик").

Рисуйте свои действия при делении на листочке в клетку и переводите их в инструкции языка.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, лучше действовать не так. Например, делим целые числа а и b и double x - результат деления.  Вводим такие условные равенства: double n=a и double k=b. Далее пишем double x=n/k, т.е. делим вещественные числа и в результате по умолчанию вещественное число.
Попробуйте!